# Hibernate Criteria Subquery Restrictions

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, criteria-api

I've a criteria query and a subquery and I want to apply the restrictions of criteria query to subquery. Below is what I have tried so far.

```
CriteriaQuery<Object> query = cb.createQuery(Object.class);
Root<Entity1> entityRoot = query.from(Entity1.class);
List<Predicate> conditions = new ArrayList<>();
conditions.add(cb.equal(entityRoot.get("relatedEntity").get("id"), 2));
conditions.add(cb.or(cb.isNull(entity1Entity2Join.get("columnName")), cb.equal(entity1Entity2Join.get("columnName"), true)));
query.where(conditions.toArray(new Predicate[]{})).distinct(true);

//Subquery
Subquery<Object> subQuery = cb.createQuery().subquery(Object.class);
subQuery.where(query.getRestriction()); // I want to apply the criteria query restrictions here but Hibernate is throwing exception of invalid path.
```

Any ideas would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is normal that you get that error and the operation is correct, in the end you are trying to establish in the where of the subquery some conditions of a new query to which you have not defined anything, to solve it try changing this line

```
Subquery <Object> subQuery = cb.createQuery().subquery(Object.class);
```

for this

```
Subquery <Object> subQuery = query.subquery(Object.class);
```

creating the subquery from the query that you had already created, and not creating a new query and a subquery from this